# Trying to setState, but function is returning null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, lifecycle

I am using React with Spotify's Web API and trying to setState. I am using React's life cycle method as well, but it keeps returning null.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchNewReleases()
}

fetchNewReleases() {
  const options = {
    "items": {
       "album_type": "single"
     }
  }

  const items = spotifyWebApi.getNewReleases(options, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err)
    }
    else {
      data.albums.items.filter(item => {
        return item.album_type = "single"
      })
    }
  })

  this.setState({
    items:items
  }) 
}
```

Could anyone explain why please?

Comment: What is it that "keep returning null"? You'll have to be more specific. At first glance it appears that you are calling `this.setState()` immediately after starting an asynchronous  `spotifyWebApi.getNewReleases()`. Try putting your `setState` in the callback of the API fetch so that it has the data available.

Comment: You can use the second parameter of setState, a callback.

`example:`      
this.setState({ key: val }, callBack) .   

documents: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). `items` don't exist at the moment when `setState` is called. Asynchronous `getNewReleases` call won't return a result because it doesn't exist yet.

It should be:

```
  spotifyWebApi.getNewReleases(options, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err)
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        items: data.albums.items.filter(item => {
         return item.album_type === "single"
        })
      });
    }
  });
```

Notice that `getNewReleases` callback should be arrow function in order to get correct `this`.

Comment: worked like a charm! I was wondering also is there a way to chain on a .then method to deal with the async call?

Comment: If API you're using uses no promises you need to convert it to a promise first.

Comment: the filter method gets a predicate function (=== instead of =)

Comment: @ArtemKha Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchNewReleases()
}

 fetchNewReleases = () => {
          const options = {
            "items": {
              "album_type": "single"
            }
          }
          spotifyWebApi.getNewReleases(options, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            }
            else {
              let items = data.albums.items.filter(item => {
                return item.album_type = "single"
              })
              this.setState({
                items:items
              })
            }
          })

        }
```

Comment: What @Shivam means to say is that the callback passed to getNewReleases is called after an async request completes (probably).  Therefore, you must do the setState within that callback.  Placing setState on the line after getNewReleases runs it right away, which is too early.